# what is wrong with the printing, it stop at someplace not loading to print

Tags: java, printing

**Here is my CODE to deleted everything inside the <>.**

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner Theinput = GetUserInput (console);


  while (Theinput.hasNextLine()){
     String Input = Theinput.nextLine();
     Scanner text = new Scanner(Input);

     if (text.hasNext()){

        String MyNewText = Input;
        while(MyNewText.contains("<") || MyNewText.contains(">") ){

           int Max = MyNewText.indexOf ( ">" );
           int Min = MyNewText.indexOf ( "<" );
           String Replacement = "";
           String ToReplacement = MyNewText.substring (Min,Max+1);
           MyNewText = MyNewText.replaceAll(ToReplacement,Replacement); 
        }
        System.out.println (MyNewText);
     }

     else {
        System.out.println();
     }
  }
 }
```

**i basically is try to converge a this text**

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Basic HTML Sample Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">
<CENTER>
<H1>A Simple Sample Web Page</H1>



<IMG SRC="http://sheldonbrown.com/images/scb_eagle_contact.jpeg">





<H4>By Sheldon Brown</H4>

<H2>Demonstrating a few HTML features</H2>

</CENTER>

HTML is really a very simple language. It consists of ordinary text, with
commands that are enclosed by "<" and ">" characters, or bewteen an "&" and a ";". <P>


You don't really need to know much HTML to create a page, because you can copy bits
of HTML from other pages that do what you want, then change the text!<P>


This page shows on the left as it appears in your browser, and the corresponding HTML
code appears on the right. The HTML commands are linked to explanations of what they                             do.




   <H3>Line Breaks</H3>

HTML doesn't normally use line breaks for ordinary text. A white space of any size is
treated as a single space. This is because the author of the page has no way of knowing
the size of the reader's screen, or what size type they will have their browser set     for.<P>



If you want to put a line break at a particular place, you can use the "<BR>" command,
or, for a paragraph break, the "<P>" command, which will insert a blank line.
The heading command ("<4></4>") puts a blank line above and below the heading text.



<H4>Starting and Stopping Commands</H4>

Most HTML commands come in pairs: for example, "<H4>" marks the beginning of a size 4
heading, and "</H4>" marks the end of it. The closing command is always the same as the
opening command, except for the addition of the "/".<P>



Modifiers are sometimes included along with the basic command, inside the opening
command's < >. The modifier does not need to be repeated in the closing command.





<H1>This is a size "1" heading</H1>

<H2>This is a size "2" heading</H2>

<H3>This is a size "3" heading</H3>

<H4>This is a size "4" heading</H4>

<H5>This is a size "5" heading</H5>

<H6>This is a size "6" heading</H6>

<center>

<H4>Copyright ?1997, by
<A HREF="http://sheldonbrown.com/index.html">Sheldon Brown</A>
</H4>

If you would like to make a link or bookmark to this page, the URL is:
<BR> http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html</body>
```

**after all i my output stop at and everything work but just that.**

**I JUST HAD NO IDEA THAT WHAT HAPPEN TO THE PRINTLN()**

**This is a size "5" heading**

**This i**

Comment: Please use a parser instead.

Comment: Take a while to study Java naming conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367 variables and methods should start with lower case and be camelCased.

Comment: sorry...about the naming conventions i just new to java. and my code is not working some how i think the code should do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
String out = "<TITLE>Basic HTML Sample Page</TITLE>".replaceAll("</?[a-zA-Z0-9]+?>", "");
System.out.println(out);
```

you can try regular expression, but it can't handle something like

```
<a
  href="http://google.com"
  target="_blank"
>google</a>
```

maybe you should consider using a parser, for example [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org)